# algorithm to draw image selection

Tags: algorithm, image-processing

I have an image with size of M*N. Each pixel can be selected or not selected.

[image: image selection]

Given selection values for each pixel (selected or not), what is the most efficient algorithm to get the set of polygons which represents a selection?

[image]

Comment: If your example the selection mask contains only connected lines that are already polygons. What exactly is the question?

Comment: Edited the question. The selection mask contains selection value for each pixel, not lines or polygons.

Comment: @razor3x "*Given selection values for each pixel (selected or not)*" you mean that you will provide **MxN** Binary Array with `1, 0` values `1` selected, `0` Non selected? or just the corner points, or the bordering Lines?

Comment: @Bilal It is MxN binary array with `1, 0` values for each pixel

Comment: @razor3x you need two simple steps: **1.** `cv2.findContours` to find contours, **2.** `cv2.approxPolyDP` to approximate them into polygons, see this [tutorial](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contour_features/py_contour_features.html) for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Diagonals might be tricky, because of pixel-exact rounding errors, so I would go only for rectangles with horizontal and vertical lines (overlapping ones can be merges to a polygon)

I would perform the following steps:

1. connect selected neighbours of selected pixels to horizontal lines
2. connect horizontal lines to rectangles
3. connect overlapping/touching rectangles to a polygon

Answer (score 1):

I think any filling algorithm can be suitable:

- get a selected pixel not already used
- start from it and fill the surface defined by all its connected pixels
- this will define a polygon (just retain horizontal/vertical extremas)
- restart with any selected pixel already not considered to get another polygon